# bad request error when creating a bigquery table from pandas

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a dataframe for with which I want to create a bigquery table, I already have the enviroment variables and the client instance:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "C://Users/56982/path_to_cred/my_credentias.json" 
bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
```

With this bigquery_client I'm able to read a tables but I´m having issues to create a new table.

This is the code I´m trying:

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df,"mpl-my-project.project.test_table")
```

And this is the error I get:

GenericGBQException:

```
Reason: 400 POST 

Invalid dataset ID "mpl-my-project.project".
Dataset IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores) and must be at most 1024 characters long.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "-" in the dataset name. Try this "mpl_my_project":

```
pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df,"mpl_my_project.project.test_table")
```